# Java ResourceBundle changing to default language

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have created the following [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) in Java which reads from the correct MessegesBundle_en_GB.properties file:

```java
ResourceBundle labels = 
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessegesBundle",new Locale( "en", "GB"));
labels.getString("Test");
```

However when I try using another language (Scottish Gaelic) it simply defaults back to en_GB

```java
ResourceBundle labels = 
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessegesBundle",new Locale( "gd", "GB"));
system.out.println(labels.getLocale()); // returns en-GB
labels.getString("Test");
```

Looking through the list of Available Locales from `Locale.getAvailableLocales();` and "gd" doesn't appear.

Does this mean I can't use `ResourceBundle` for I18N or is there a way of either adding Gaelic or forcing `ResourceBundle` to use the correct properties file?

Thanks

Comment: have you created the MessegesBundle_gd_GB.properties file and kept in classpath

Comment: i have tried this example on my machine it is working fine

Comment: Yeah its working at my end on a different computer as well. Will try again tomorrow after a Clean and Build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locales returned by `getAvailableLocales()` are not very important as you can create new ones the way you did: `new Locale( "gd", "GB")`.

As stated in the [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) java docs the locale main purpose is to identify resources: resource bundles, number formats, etc. The strings identifying the `Locale` are not even validated upon creation.

My guess is that you don't have the MessegesBundle_gd_GB.properties resource available in the classpath.

Comment: Yup had misspelled the `MessegesBundle_gd_GB.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to have that charset language installed to load it, I suppose you could "force" it however when serving a page but you would need to pick up information specificaly from the user as a request for that page language to be assigned.